# Postgres UPDATE x WHERE id IN y

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, postgresql-performance

This has probably been asked before, but googling for keywords like "IN" doesn't work very well.

This is my query:

```
UPDATE tblCustomer SET type = 2 
WHERE idcustomer                                
IN (SELECT fidcustomer1
    FROM tblorder                   
     UNION                      
    SELECT fidcustomer2
    FROM tblorder                   
   )
```

To break it down: I want to set the type (just an int) of all customers to 2 for all customers that appear in the order-table, in one of either column.

On my test data, none of these tables contain more than a few hundred rows, yet the query runs for many minutes (even without the UNION, that doesn't seem to make much of a difference), apparently re-doing the inner query once per row in customer. I could obviously rewrite it into a single SELECT DISTINCT(id), followed by a few hundred single-row updates and do the logic in whatever language I use for my ODBC-access, but that's just a hack.

How can I rewrite this properly?

Addendum: The table I want to update contains a lot of relatively large BYTEA blobs, a few MB per row. They are set to Storage External or Extended, but I wonder if that could make the sequential scans slow. All updates seem to take a long time, not just this one.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is useful for performance questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-------------------------------
-- Use two EXISTS:
-------------------------------
UPDATE tblCustomer tc
SET type = 2
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tblorder ex
    WHERE ex.fidcustomer1 = tc.idcustomer
    )
OR EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tblorder ex
    WHERE ex.fidcustomer2 = tc.idcustomer
    );

-------------------------------
-- or combine the two EXISTS::
-------------------------------
UPDATE tblCustomer tc
SET type = 2 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tblorder ex
    WHERE ex.fidcustomer1 = tc.idcustomer
    OR ex.fidcustomer2 = tc.idcustomer
    );
```

My gut feeling is that the first version (with two separate exists) will perform better, because the executor could *short-circuit* if one of the existss would yield `True`. That would avoid the removal-of-duplicates phase (and probably sorting), which is inherent to the UNION construct.

Comment: With lots of duplicates this might be faster than my solution. For just 10 - 20 % probably not. The proof of the pudding is in the eating.

Comment: The problem is that the removal-of-duplicates also has to take place if no actual duplicates are present (the planner cannot know this). The sorting step (N log N) will always be needed, (unless a very small amount of data is to be processed, and hash or bitmap/index operations can be used). A little experimentation indicated that my two-exists version was always the fastest. Sometimes Erwin#2 was about the same (and sometimes it even produced the same query plan). Note: I added indexes on FK1 and FK2.

Comment: I've switched my implementation to a variant of your version. They all perform very similar on my data, but this one works in SQLite, whereas the UPDATE FROM variants do not.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest a simpler approach:

```
UPDATE tblCustomer c
SET    type = 2 
FROM   tblorder o
WHERE  c.idcustomer IN (o.fidcustomer1, o.fidcustomer2)
AND    c.type IS DISTINCT FROM 2  -- optional, to avoid empty updates
```

Except, if there are **duplicates** in `tblorder`, then a similar approach to what you had is sensible:

```
UPDATE tblCustomer c
SET    type = 2 
FROM  (
    SELECT fidcustomer1 AS cust FROM tblorder
    UNION
    SELECT fidcustomer2 FROM tblorder
    ) o
WHERE  c.idcustomer = o.cust
AND    c.type IS DISTINCT FROM 2;
```

Either way, in PostgreSQL, joining in a table regularly performs better than an `IN` expression.

Comment: In my test database, the duplicates are sparse. In the real environment, I expect some customers to be responsible for as much as 10% to 20% of the orders and duplicates the norm.

Comment: @Kdansky: Then go with the second query. `UNION` removes the dupes. Any remaining performance problems would not be due to this query. You would have to inspect your table more closely. Triggers? Heavy concurrent write load?

Comment: This version performs fast enough. Thanks.